# How to add SSL to the backend mysql database and connect using Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, ssl, connection

I have a requirement to add SSL to the backend mysql database and connect using Laravel. But unable to know the way to do it.
Do I need to have MySql Db  configured to use encrypted connection and then provide some parameters in Database.php file in Laravel.

My site has https enabled.

Please guide what should be taken care and to be done.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to is first configure SSL/TLS on your MySQL Server and the instructions will be specific to the OS hosting the MySQL Server as well as the MySQL Version itself.

Here's an example guide for MySQL 5.x and Ubuntu:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Once you've done this, you can configure your laravel app to tell it how to communicate over encrypted mysql connection by adding this line to your db config:

```
'options' => array(    
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => $cert_base . '/ssl-ca-bundle.pem'
 ),
```

the full config will look something like this in **config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  'strict' => true,
  'engine' => null,
  'options' => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/path/to/ssl-ca-bundle.pem'
  ),
),
```

Comment: what is this "ssl-ca-bundle.pem" and how and from where I will get this file, and where it generally resides. Please guide.

Comment: That would be the SSL certificate bundle your MySQL server is running - from the first guide I linked to.